# High latency between spout -> bolt and bolt -> bolts

Tags: apache-storm

In my topology I see around 1 - 2 ms latency when transferring tuples from spouts to bolts or from bolts to bolts. I am calculating latency using nanosecond timestamps because the whole topology runs inside a single worker. 
Topology is run in a cluster which runs in a production capable hardware.

To my understanding, tuples need not be serialized/de-serialized in this case as everything is inside single JVM. I have set parallelism hint for most spouts and bolts to 5 and spouts only produce events at a rate of 100 per second. I dont think high latency is due to queuing of events because I dont see any increase of latency with time. No memory increase either. log levels are set to ERROR. CPU usage is in the range of 200 to 300 %.

what could be causing this latency? I was expecting only few us's for tuple transfer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using one of the released Storm versions, and not 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, since the queueing implementation has changed in that version.

I think it's likely that the delay is because Storm batches up tuples before delivering them to the consumer. Take a look at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.1/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/utils/DisruptorQueue.java#L247, and also look at the Flusher class in that file. When a spout/bolt publishes a tuple, it is put into the _currentBatch list. It stays there until either enough tuples have been received so the batch is "big enough" (you can look at the _inputBatchSize variable to figure out when this is), or until the Flusher is triggered (happens by default once per millisecond).

Comment: I am using stable 1.0.6 version. I tried your suggestion. Essentially I set the batch size to 1 and timeout to 1ms. It certainly improved things, but still the mean latency is above 600 us and some times reaches around 2000 us. I was actually looking for very low latency transfer of tuples in the range of 1 - 40 us when everything runs in the same JVM. Is this doable in storm? Or am I evaluating wrong framework for my low latency app?

Comment: Storm would usually run clustered on multiple machines, so I'd expect that you'd usually see higher latencies than that due to network lag. Storm tends to optimize for throughput rather than latency I think. Try posting on the storm-user mailing list (https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html) about your use case, and why you need this kind of latency, it's likely people there will know if it's possible.

Comment: cheers, I posted in that group and they confirmed that latencies I see are usual unless I need to upgrade to unstable version 2.